# How to call a trait method with alias

Tags: php, class, laravel, namespaces, traits

I'm trying to place a trait inside a class called Page. I also need to rename a trait function so that it doesn't clash with an existing class function. I *thought* I did all this successfully however I get an error that points to the wrong location?!

`Call to undefined function App\Pages\Models\myTraitDefaultScope()`

I've also tried: `MyTrait\defaultScope($query)` instead of trying to rename the conflicting function. But I then get the following error:

`Call to undefined function App\MyTrait\defaultScope()`

Below is the trait and class contained in separate files.

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

trait MyTrait{
    public function defaultScope($query){
        return $query->where('active', '1')
    }
}
```

.

```
<?php namespace Modules\Pages\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use App\MyTrait;

class Page extends Model {

    use MyTrait{
        MyTrait::defaultScope as myTraitDefaultScope;
    }

    public function defaultScope($query){
        return myTraitDefaultScope($query);
    }
}
```

I'm not all that awesome at this so please don't shoot if I've got something badly wrong :)

Comment: Not 100 % sure, but shouldn't that be `return $this->myTraitDefaultScope($query);` so that php looks for the function on the same object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you 'use' a trait in your class, the class **inherits** all the methods and properties of the trait, like if it was extending an abstract class or an interface

So, this method of `MyTrait`:

```
public function defaultScope($query){
    return $query->where('active', '1')
}
```

will be inherited by your `Page` class

As you have aliased this method as: `myTraitDefaultScope`, to call the method you should call it in the same way you would call every other method of the  `Page` class:

```
public function defaultScope($query){

    //call the method of the class
    return $this->myTraitDefaultScope($query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up, everything's running well now! Others did answer earlier but you provided more detail!

Answer (score 3):

As you're using trait. So it points to the current or parent class. Thus, calling any method should be like **$this->method($params);** syntax.